# Variable contents keeps resetting

Tags: swift

So I want to assign a variable to equal another variable, currently I am using two variables as shown below to get the input:

```
@IBAction func beginPlayingButton(_ sender: Any) {
    playerOneName = player1TextBox.text!
    playerTwoName = player2TextBox.text!
    if(playerOneName == "" || playerTwoName == "")
    {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "TicTacToe", message:
            "Each player must have a name", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Re-enter Names", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler: nil))


        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

This code works and it will perform a segue as it passes the check, however when I try to print the player's names respectively, they are equal to null again: (This is done to check the current value of the variables)

```
if(endGameWinner == true)
        {
            print("Player one Name : " + playerOneName)
            print("Player two Name : " + playerTwoName)
            gameResultLabel.text = currentPlayerName
        }
```

[image]

I don't understand why the value assigned to the variable is resetting

The only other time these are called are here:

```
if(player % 2 != 0)
    {
        player = playerone
        currentPlayerName = playerOneName
    }
    else
    {
        player = playertwo
        currentPlayerName = playerTwoName
    }
```

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: When are these methods called? Where are `playerOneName` and `playerTwoName` defined? Can you show us more context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to fix this problem, since I was working with two viewContollers I was using a segue to show the next view controller. As a result I had to pass the information from the first viewController which is where the player names are being assigned to the second viewController.

To do this I used the prepare for segue function as shown here:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let gameViewController = segue.destination as! gameViewController
    gameViewController.playerOneName = player1TextBox.text!
    gameViewController.playerTwoName = player2TextBox.text!
}
```

This allowed me to access the subclass gameViewController where I could then assign a variable in that class to store the names. This allowed me to then change the text of a label.

For reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fbTHFH3tl4